# Celery - group inside a chain

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to use a group (or chunks) inside a chain, like:

```
chain(getRange.s(3),  GROUP() , xsum.s() )
```

Where `GROUP()` is a group of `double()` tasks, i.e. `group(double(0),double(1),double(2))`.
A similar question was posted in [How to chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group) but it's not explained how to pass the output from group to the next task in the chain.

```
@task
def getRange(x):
    return range(x)

@task
def double(nr):
    return nr*2

@task
def xsum(list):
    return sum(list)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do that with the current primitives in a single chain. Passing callbacks like in the question you mention won't allow you to listen to when the group tasks have finished. The closest you can get is something like:

```
@task
def get_range(x):
  return range(x)

@task
def mapper(nr):
  return nr * 2

@task
def reducer(nrs):
  return sum(nrs)

@task
def double_then_sum(nrs):
  return (
    group([mapper.s(nr) for nr in nrs]) |
    reducer.s()
  )()

ar = (get_range.s(3) | double_then_sum.s())() # call the procedure
ar.result.result # get the result
```

Otherwise you could try using [dynamic chaining](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/817), which would lead to a simpler solution, or just use `map` if you don't need your grouped tasks to run in parallel.

Comment: can we do like `(get_range.s(3) | double_then_sum.s() | another_task.s())` ?

Comment: I tried your example, but when I do `ar.result` it gives me list with tasks ids ```[['92e0c12c-b746-4e19-a409-1eee5d098cde',
  [['34bb5dd2-c0c6-4325-a9b9-eea2bce2aa53', None],
   [[['96fda838-f575-4989-b3d3-9873887479d6', None], None],
    [['bf5880b3-b8d5-48d1-ae65-bfba91480eca', None], None],
    [['eeb15627-e5f4-4145-a416-cd9080b7ef01', None], None]]]],
 None]```