# How can I trigger tasks from another task in Python Celery?

Tags: python, celery

```
# get a list of stuff
@celery.task
def getList():
    listOfStuff = getStuff()
    for thing in listOfStuff:
        processThing.apply_async(args=(thing))


# another attempt at list of stuff
@celery.task
def getList():
    listOfStuff = getStuff()
    for thing in listOfStuff:
        processThing.s((thing))

@celery.task
def processThing(thing):
    pass
```

So neither getList() implementation triggers the processThing tasks. I can't figure out why. I'm guessing there is a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to accomplish but I can't figure out what that is.

How can I kick off tasks from another task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
celery.execute.send_task("task.fqn", args=[], kwargs={})
```

This is command that worked to spawn my tasks.

Answer (score 4):

This situation is explained in the docs under http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Here's a previous thread that shows some code on a similar situation: [How to chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group)

Comment: I'm not really sure this is what I want. Edit, sorry, I forget that the enter key doesn't work as expected here.

The second example seems extremely bizarre to do something so simple. But I believe I have figured out what I wanted, it just wasn't clearly documented.

You can check my accepted answer and if you think there is a better way, please feel free to share ;)

Answer (score 4):

Celery does not require access to a task’s code base in order to invoke it. The trick is to invoke a task by its name, either directly via `celery_app.send_task(...)` or by creating a Signature object `celery_app.signature(...)` which is the equivalent of calling `task.s(...)` when you do have access to the task’s code base.

**more details**:
https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/06/19/call-celery-task-outside-codebase/