# Celery chains of groups feeding groups

Tags: python-2.7, celery

My question is similar to [How to chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group), which basically asks how do we do:

```
process_list = (get_list.s(10) | group(process_item.s(i) for i in ???))
```

and the answer was to fake the group with a task. Now, an issue arises if want to extend the chain beyond the last group:

```
process_list = (get_list.s(10) | dmap.s((process_item.s(i) for i in ???) | do_something.s())
```

Then `dmap` returns `GroupResults` which cannot be processed by `do_something`. Any ideas?

PS: The `dmap` solution will work only with the `pickle` encoder and not with the new standard `json` encoder.

Comment: why can't you update `do_something` to accept a `GroupResult`?

Comment: I don't know how to work with `GroupResult`, any suggestions?

Comment: [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.GroupResult)