# Celery Generating group tasks from chain task

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am trying to chain following tasks with celery(v4.0),

```
task = group([tasks1.s(), task2.s()) | generate_job_requests.s() | execute_job.map() | aggregate_result.s()
result = task.get()
```

Above part is working fine upto `generate_job_requests` as chord.
But problem starts with `execute_job` where it gets list of jobs from `generate_job_requests`, for which I need to create parallel tasks and later on aggregate result of all jobs.

I am trying to validate whether such kind of taskgraph is possible with celery ? Is there any possible alternate workflow to solve problem with such dependency ?
Anything I am missing in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used map like functionality with intermediate task creator which acts like chord,

```
@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def dmap(it, callback, end_task):
    callback = subtask(callback)
    grp = group(callback.clone([arg, ]) for arg in it)
    c = (grp | end_task)
    return c()
```

So task flow was reduced as this,

```
task = (group([tasks1.s(), task2.s()) | generate_job_requests.s() | dmap.s(
        execute_job.s(), aggregate_result.s())).apply_async()
```

For getting ultimate output of task, I did few tweaks,

```
# As we get dmap task id here
dmap_task = celery_app.AsyncResult(task.id)
dmap_result = dmap_task.get()
# Get actual aggregate_result task id
aggr_res_task_id = dmap_result[0][0]
result = celery_app.AsyncResult(aggr_res_task_id)
# Here we receive actual output of overall task
result.get()
```

I referred [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group?answertab=active#tab-top)