# How to throttle script that creates celery tasks faster than they're consumed?

Tags: python, queue, task, celery

I have a script that generates millions of Celery tasks, one per row in the DB. Is there a way to throttle it so that it doesn't completely flood Celery?

Ideally I want to keep Celery busy, but I don't want the length of the Celery queue to exceed a few dozen tasks since that's just a waste of memory (especially since without some kind of throttle the script will add millions of tasks to the queue almost instantly).

Comment: upvoted! wonderful question, i have the same case, i could have a task that could take upto 1 second on execution and i have 500 such tasks that i need to run within a second every second :) been thinking hard of how to drop existing tasks and replace with new ones or something along those lines

Comment: FWIW, we've used this in prod to process millions (?) of tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've spent some time on this problem over the past several days and came up with what I'm calling a `CeleryThrottle` object. Basically, you tell it how many items you want in a queue and it does its best to keep the queue between that size and 2× that size.

So here's the code (assumes Redis broker, but easily changed):

```
# coding=utf-8
from collections import deque

import time

import redis
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.timezone import now


def get_queue_length(queue_name='celery'):
    """Get the number of tasks in a celery queue.

    :param queue_name: The name of the queue you want to inspect.
    :return: the number of items in the queue.
    """
    r = redis.StrictRedis(
        host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
        port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
        db=settings.REDIS_DATABASES['CELERY'],
    )
    return r.llen(queue_name)


class CeleryThrottle(object):
    """A class for throttling celery."""

    def __init__(self, min_items=100, queue_name='celery'):
        """Create a throttle to prevent celery run aways.

        :param min_items: The minimum number of items that should be enqueued. 
        A maximum of 2× this number may be created. This minimum value is not 
        guaranteed and so a number slightly higher than your max concurrency 
        should be used. Note that this number includes all tasks unless you use
        a specific queue for your processing.
        """
        self.min = min_items
        self.max = self.min * 2

        # Variables used to track the queue and wait-rate
        self.last_processed_count = 0
        self.count_to_do = self.max
        self.last_measurement = None
        self.first_run = True

        # Use a fixed-length queue to hold last N rates
        self.rates = deque(maxlen=15)
        self.avg_rate = self._calculate_avg()

        # For inspections
        self.queue_name = queue_name

    def _calculate_avg(self):
        return float(sum(self.rates)) / (len(self.rates) or 1)

    def _add_latest_rate(self):
        """Calculate the rate that the queue is processing items."""
        right_now = now()
        elapsed_seconds = (right_now - self.last_measurement).total_seconds()
        self.rates.append(self.last_processed_count / elapsed_seconds)
        self.last_measurement = right_now
        self.last_processed_count = 0
        self.avg_rate = self._calculate_avg()

    def maybe_wait(self):
        """Stall the calling function or let it proceed, depending on the queue.

        The idea here is to check the length of the queue as infrequently as 
        possible while keeping the number of items in the queue as closely 
        between self.min and self.max as possible.

        We do this by immediately enqueueing self.max items. After that, we 
        monitor the queue to determine how quickly it is processing items. Using 
        that rate we wait an appropriate amount of time or immediately press on.
        """
        self.last_processed_count += 1
        if self.count_to_do > 0:
            # Do not wait. Allow process to continue.
            if self.first_run:
                self.first_run = False
                self.last_measurement = now()
            self.count_to_do -= 1
            return

        self._add_latest_rate()
        task_count = get_queue_length(self.queue_name)
        if task_count > self.min:
            # Estimate how long the surplus will take to complete and wait that
            # long + 5% to ensure we're below self.min on next iteration.
            surplus_task_count = task_count - self.min
            wait_time = (surplus_task_count / self.avg_rate) * 1.05
            time.sleep(wait_time)

            # Assume we're below self.min due to waiting; max out the queue.
            if task_count < self.max:
                self.count_to_do = self.max - self.min
            return

        elif task_count <= self.min:
            # Add more items.
            self.count_to_do = self.max - task_count
            return
```

Usage looks like:

```
throttle = CeleryThrottle()
for item in really_big_list_of_items:
    throttle.maybe_wait()
    my_task.delay(item)
```

Pretty simple and hopefully pretty flexible. With that in place, the code will monitor your queue and add waits to your loop if the queue is getting too long. This is in [our github repo](https://github.com/freelawproject/courtlistener/blob/master/cl/lib/celery_utils.py) in case there are updates.

As it does this, it will track the rolling average speed of the task, and will attempt not to check the queue length more frequently than needed. For example, if tasks take two minutes each to run, after putting 100 items in teh queue, it can wait quite a while before having to check the length of the queue again. A simpler version of this script could check the queue length every time through the loop, but that would add unnecessary delay. This version tries to be smart about it at the cost of being sometimes wrong (in which case the queue goes below `min_items`).