# Cloning a celery chain

Tags: celery, python-3.6, celery-canvas

I have an interesting issue attempting to clone a celery chain for use in a group, my intended use case is something like `group([chain.clone(args=args) for args in it])` however it keeps complaining about not having enough arguments.

I have broken this down using the below

in a file named `tasks.py`

```
@app.task
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

and then from the python shell

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> chain=add.s()|add.s(1)
>>> chain
magic_carpet.celery.add() | add(1)
>>> chain.args
()
>>> chain.delay(2,2)
<AsyncResult: fcc97c30-4700-47a6-aeb6-ffca19a1446f>
>>> cloned_chain=chain.clone(args=(2,))
>>> cloned_chain.args
()
>>> cloned_chain.delay(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bjorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/magic_carpet-PeFVEcL-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 179, in delay
    return self.apply_async(partial_args, partial_kwargs)
  File "/home/bjorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/magic_carpet-PeFVEcL-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 557, in apply_async
    dict(self.options, **options) if options else self.options))
  File "/home/bjorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/magic_carpet-PeFVEcL-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 584, in run
    first_task.apply_async(**options)
  File "/home/bjorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/magic_carpet-PeFVEcL-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 218, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/home/bjorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/magic_carpet-PeFVEcL-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 513, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>>
```

obviously, `clone` isn't replacing the args in the cloned copy of the chain, but I'm uncertain why, the `_chain` class has the clone method implemented documented as

```
>>> from celery.canvas import _chain
>>> help(_chain.clone)

Help on function clone in module celery.canvas:

clone(self, *args, **kwargs)
    Create a copy of this signature.

    Arguments:
        args (Tuple): Partial args to be prepended to the existing args.
        kwargs (Dict): Partial kwargs to be merged with existing kwargs.
        options (Dict): Partial options to be merged with
            existing options.
```

Reading the celery source I see nothing obvious that would cause this.

Currently running Celery 4.2.1 and Python 3.6.6

Is this functionality broken somehow, unsupported, or am I being incredibly obtuse and doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that the core issue is that via a roundabout course, clone calls the constructor to chain to create the new instance. this constructor does not accept any args or kwargs to apply to the chain and instead defaults them to empty values causing them to get lost.

My solution at this point is to work around the issue by creating my own clone method that modifies the arguments to the first task in the chain. while setting the args attribute appears to also work, if the chain gets cloned again within celery the values stored within it are lost.

my clone method currently supports cloning `tasks` and `chains`, though adding support for `groups` would be a trivial extension

```
def clone_signature(sig, args=(), kwargs=(), **opts):
    if sig.subtask_type and sig.subtask_type != "chain":
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Cloning only supported for Tasks and chains, not %s" % sig.subtask_type
        )
    clone = sig.clone()
    if hasattr(clone, "tasks"):
        t = clone.tasks[0]
    else:
        t = clone
    args, kwargs, opts = t._merge(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, options=opts)
    t.update(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, options=deepcopy(opts))
    return clone
```