# How to recursively chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?

Tags: python, celery

I started from this question: [How to chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13271056/3189)

But I want to expand twice.  So in my use case I have:

- task A: determines total number of items for a given date
- task B: downloads 1000 metadata entries for that date
- task C: download the content for one item

So each step I'm expanding the number of items of the next step.  I can do it by looping through the results in my task and calling `.delay()` on the next task function.  But I thought I'd try to not make my main tasks do that.  Instead they'd return a list of tuples - each tuple would then be expanded into the arguments for a call to the next function.

The above question has an answer that appears to meet my need, but I can't work out the correct way of chaining it for a two level expansion.

Here is a very cut down example of my code:

```py
from celery import group
from celery.task import subtask
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

from .celery import app

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def task_range(upper=10):
    # wrap in list to make JSON serializer work
    return list(zip(range(upper), range(upper)))

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info(f'x is {x} and y is {y}')
    char = chr(ord('a') + x)
    char2 = chr(ord('a') + x*2)
    result = x + y
    logger.info(f'result is {result}')
    return list(zip(char * result, char2 * result))

@app.task
def combine_log(c1, c2):
    logger.info(f'combine log is {c1}{c2}')

@app.task
def dmap(args_iter, celery_task):
    """
    Takes an iterator of argument tuples and queues them up for celery to run with the function.
    """
    logger.info(f'in dmap, len iter: {len(args_iter)}')
    callback = subtask(celery_task)
    run_in_parallel = group(callback.clone(args) for args in args_iter)
    return run_in_parallel.delay()
```

I've then tried various ways to make my nested mapping work.  First, a one level mapping works fine, so:

```py
pp = (task_range.s() | dmap.s(add.s()))
pp(2)
```

Produces the kind of results I'd expect, so I'm not totally off.

But when I try to add another level:

```py
ppp = (task_range.s() | dmap.s(add.s() | dmap.s(combine_log.s())))
```

Then in the worker I see the error:

```
[2019-11-23 22:34:12,024: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task proj.tasks.dmap[e92877a9-85ce-4f16-88e3-d6889bc27867] raised unexpected: TypeError("add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hdowner/dev/playground/celery/proj/tasks.py", line 44, in dmap
    return run_in_parallel.delay()
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 186, in delay
    return self.apply_async(partial_args, partial_kwargs)
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1008, in apply_async
    args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **options))
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1092, in _apply_tasks
    **options)
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 578, in apply_async
    dict(self.options, **options) if options else self.options))
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 607, in run
    first_task.apply_async(**options)
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 229, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/home/hdowner/.venv/play_celery/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 532, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

And I'm not sure why changing the argument to `dmap()` from a plain task signature to a chain changes how the arguments get passed into `add()`.  My impression was that it shouldn't, it just means the return value of `add()` would get passed on.  But apparently that is not the case ...

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the problem is that the `clone()` method on a `chain` instance does not pass the arguments through at some point - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442344/3189 for the full details.  If I use the method in that answer, my `dmap()` code becomes:

```py
@app.task
def dmap(args_iter, celery_task):
    """
    Takes an iterator of argument tuples and queues them up for celery to run with the function.
    """
    callback = subtask(celery_task)
    run_in_parallel = group(clone_signature(callback, args) for args in args_iter)
    return run_in_parallel.delay()


def clone_signature(sig, args=(), kwargs=(), **opts):
    """
    Turns out that a chain clone() does not copy the arguments properly - this
    clone does.
    From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442344/3189
    """
    if sig.subtask_type and sig.subtask_type != "chain":
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Cloning only supported for Tasks and chains, not {}".format(sig.subtask_type)
        )
    clone = sig.clone()
    if hasattr(clone, "tasks"):
        task_to_apply_args_to = clone.tasks[0]
    else:
        task_to_apply_args_to = clone
    args, kwargs, opts = task_to_apply_args_to._merge(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, options=opts)
    task_to_apply_args_to.update(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, options=deepcopy(opts))
    return clone
```

And then when I do:

```py
ppp = (task_range.s() | dmap.s(add.s() | dmap.s(combine_log.s())))
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: Can we do like `(task_range.s() | dmap.s(add.s() | dmap.s(combine_log.s())) | some_tasks.s())` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great answer.  I had to tweak the code to make sure it could handle tasks with single arguments.  I am sure this is awful, but it works!  Any improvements appreciated.

```
@celery_app.task(name='app.worker.dmap')
def dmap(args_iter, celery_task):
    """
    Takes an iterator of argument tuples and queues them up for celery to run with the function.
    """
    callback = subtask(celery_task)
    print(f"ARGS: {args_iter}")
    args_list = []
    run_in_parallel = group(clone_signature(callback, args if type(args) is list else [args]) for args in args_iter)
    print(f"Finished Loops: {run_in_parallel}")
    return run_in_parallel.delay()
```

Specifically - I added:

```
if type(args) is list else [args]
```

to this line:

```
run_in_parallel = group(clone_signature(callback, args ***if type(args) is list else [args]***) for args in args_iter)
```