# chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group in middle of chain

Tags: python, celery

This question is the same as this one:
[How to chain a Celery task that returns a list into a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group)
except that I need this to happen in the middle of a chain, and the accepted solution only works if the intermediate task is the final "link" in the chain.

Here is the same example slightly modified that reproduces the issue:

```py
from random import random

from celery import 

@app.task
def get_list(amount):
    return [i for i in range(amount)]

@app.task
def process_item(item):
    return [f'id-{item}', random() > .5]

@app.task
def dmap(it, callback):
    # Map a callback over an iterator and return as a group
    callback = subtask(callback)
    return group(callback.clone([arg,]) for arg in it)()

@app.task
def handle_results(results):
    for result in results:
        if result[1] == None:
            continue

        return result[1] # return the first True value

def foo():
    return chain(
        get_list.s(10),
        dmap.s(process_item.s()),
        handle_results.s() # <-- if I add this, it fails
    )

# in a terminal, or somewhere
foo()()
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
>       raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
>   kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type GroupResult is not JSON serializable

That is the return value of `dmap` after all.. and no it can't be serialized.. but note that if I did this:

```py
>>> lst = [i for i in range(amount)]
>>> chain(group(process_item.s(i) for i in lst), handle_results.s())
```

then that would work. I'm confused on what actually needs to be passed from one member of the chain to the other.. as the result of `group(...)` is:

```py
>>> from app.manager_tasks import process_item
>>> group(process_item.s(e) for e in [1, 2, 3, 4])
group([app.manager_tasks.process_item(1), process_item(2), process_item(3), process_item(4)])
>>> group(process_item.s(e) for e in [1, 2, 3, 4]).delay()
<GroupResult: 07c9be1a-b3e3-4da2-af54-7177f3d91d0f [cf777f54-4763-46bd-a405-2c1993ddbf66, 103298fc-8f1f-4183-ba45-670224fcd319, 3ad87c2c-7b64-4309-a61b-e53ae17302b9, bf2766a3-662a-415d-a35b-037a0476f4a4]>
```

which is a `GroupResult` itself (with delay called), otherwise just a group. Since the `dmap` is a signature itself, I'm guessing that's why `delay()` needs to be called inside of it for `chain`..

If [I invoke the result](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#partials) as done in the other [stackoverflow (same link as first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271056/how-to-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013002/how-to-recursively-chain-a-celery-task-that-returns-a-list-into-a-group) I'm left with a `GroupResult`, which only succeeds if it's the last member of the chain (`()`, `.delay()`, `.apply_async()`). If I call `.get()` on the `GroupResult` to get something serializable, then I get the following error: `RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task!` Which presents me with a conundrum; how can I accomplish this?

Pretty stumped on this one.. but I'm also new to celery. Really appreciate any advice on how I could/should solve this!

A bit more background, I intend to use this chain in repeat as part of another chain which sits at the top level specifying stages in a pipeline.

Comment: As far as I know, you can run any task in the middle of the chain, but that task can't become part of the chain. Since you must not call .get() inside a task, you should create a chord (basically another chain where final task will "collect" data), whose final task stores the state that you poll from your "main" chain before it finishes. Most distributed task queues that claim they are better then Celery would not even allow you to dynamically create your workflow, not to mention to dynamically modify primitives...

Comment: Thank you @DejanLekic! that was exactly the answer I needed. I'll post my solution that I gathered using your feedback. I should have been using a `chord` as you said. I'm curious what you mean by another chain where the final task collects the data. I was only able to continue the chord with a chain if I made the continuing chain part of the callback itself since a `chord` returns an `AsyncResult` and not a `Signature`. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DejanLekic mentioned, I should have been using a `chord`. This would solve the above:

```py
def foo():
    return chord(
        get_list.s(10),
        dmap.s(process_item.s())
    )(handle_results.s())
```

I had wanted this to still yet be part of a `chain`, but it [doesn't look like that is supported](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5490#issuecomment-511537591) right now.

---

The below is less related to the question, though possibly useful to some.

Using the solution from that github issue thread, I can still do what I need (after the primary question was figured out) by having nested chords and chains. Not the cleanest, but it works.. would look like this:

```py
def foo():
    return chord(
        get_list.s(10),
        dmap.s(process_item.s())
    )(chain(handle_results.s(), log_stuff.s()))
```

Comment: Chord *is* a chain effectively - a chain of Group and a final task.

Answer (score 0):

As I could not get the accepted answer to work, here is another take on this, where the chord is dealt with inside the dmap function.

Here is a reproducible example :

```py
from celery import Celery, subtask, group
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://', broker='redis://')


@app.task
def get_list(n):
    return [i for i in range(n)]


@app.task
def process_item(item):
    return f'id-{item}'


@app.task
def handle_results(results):
    return ' - '.join(results)


@app.task
def dmap(it, callback, chord_callback):
    # Map a callback over an iterator and return as a group
    callback = subtask(callback)
    chord_callback = subtask(chord_callback)
    final_res = (group(callback.clone((arg,)) for arg in it) |
                 chord_callback)()
    return final_res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipeline = (get_list.s(10) |
                dmap.s(process_item.s(), handle_results.s()))()
    task_ids = pipeline.get()
    chord_task_id = task_ids[0][0]
    print(app.AsyncResult(chord_task_id).get())
    # id-0 - id-1 - id-2 - id-3 - id-4 - id-5 - id-6 - id-7 - id-8 - id-9
```

What happens here is:

- The `get_list` task produces a 0:9 range, which is chained with the `dmap` task.
- The `dmap` task deserializes two callback signatures, and runs a chord task asynchronously where the first callback (here, transforming to an "id-." label) is applied on each element of the list, and the second one is subsequently applied on the list of results (here joining the labels to a single string). (The chord is implicit here as "Chaining a group together with another task will automatically upgrade it to be a chord", from the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives))
- This pipeline finally returns all tasks ids, and the final result can be fetched e.g. with `get` from the chord id

Tested on celery v5.2.7